# DDD and SOA application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, domain-driven-design

I am responsible of a large SOA application. Client is ASP.NET WebForms and business is .NET with WCF.

Our business code is really bad (BBOM) and after some reading, I fall into DDD. I really want to rewrite some parts of our business with DDD concepts.

With SOA, I'm in a stateless world. So if a web page gives the ability to the user to manipulate orders, for example, like add order detail, remove order detail, ... each business method has to reload datas to hydrate my aggregate before applying business rules and persist changes.

When few data are conerned, it's not a problem. But what happens when an aggregate is large and it takes some seconds for loading data and hydrating it ?

Is it possible to use SOA architecture in a statefull manner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [one definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_statelessness_principle) of SOA statelessness,

> The Service Statelessness principle provides guidelines in favor of
>   making the service stateless by **shifting away** the state management
>   overhead from the services **to some other external architectural**
>   **component**

Thus, state is deferred from the service to something else but obviously, it doesn't entirely disappear.

All options are open as to where to defer state. You mentioned the potential performance problems of storing it in a database, but have you experienced them in the first place ? It's the most common form of domain state storage in DDD applications, and as a general good practice, Aggregates should be small.

Other options include storing state in the client, in a session mechanism provided by your web framework, in a cookie, etc. Make sure you understand the ins and outs of each one to make an educated choice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with just about every server model. You need to have a mechanism to start a 'session' and give the client a token of some sort (ie a session handle) which they then use on every subsequent request.

In your server implementation you keep the state of the sessions in some table or Dictionary, retrieve the session and handle the request based on the data for the session - you keep the session alive for as long as possible.

If there is no activity on sessions for a while you either

1. kill the sessions outright, or
2. save the session state in some DB and then kill the session.

When the user has finished they 'log out' - also killing the session.

So individual SOA requests are indeed stateless, but they refer (by dint of the session handle) to a stateful object.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use SOA architecture in a statefull manner?

I think so, like @Uebercoder said. But it doesn't mean you can't use DDD.

We all know that the steps:

- load the aggregate
- update it (in memory)
- persist it again

Will never be faster than:

- Just update (ie) that column in the database

But with the second option we lose one of the main benefits of DDD: expose the business in the code. If all your actions are just a "update that property and save", maybe this project will not benefit from DDD after all.

In my experience, using DDD inside SOA architecture worth it in the most cases. You just need, as @guillaume31 said, be careful of the size and boundaries of your aggregate roots.

Just cherry picking one of your phrases:

> "large SOA application"

I don't know exacly what you mean with this, but beware: monolithic applications implemented in DDD gets messy really fast.

I think ([and Eric Evans too](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/06/dddx-microservices-boundaries)) DDD really shines inside of a **microservices** architecture.

*Just my thoughts :)*